# Unable to delete tables in schema.rb from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems, schema.rb

I use Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.3.0

I have a small Rails App. At first I wanted to assign different roles to each user based what he/she had signed up for. So i tried out the "Royce" gem from  https://github.com/MartinJNash/Royce

I uninstalled it after seeing that it was too complicated for my requirements.

Then I tried the "simple-roles" gem to see how it works from here https://github.com/stanislaw/simple_roles. I uninstalled tat too. I ran db:migrate when I had these 2 gems in my app.

Now I don't want the corresponding tables from these two gems in my schema.rb. Its not exactly interfering with my app, but I would like to delete them.

The following is my schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160911213902) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name:  "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree

add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", using: :btree

  create_table "royce_connector", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "roleable_id",   null: false
    t.string   "roleable_type", null: false
    t.integer  "role_id",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "royce_connector", ["role_id"], name: "index_royce_connector_on_role_id", using: :btree
  add_index "royce_connector", ["roleable_id", "roleable_type"], name: "index_royce_connector_on_roleable_id_and_roleable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "royce_role", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "royce_role", ["name"], name: "index_royce_role_on_name", using: :btree

  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "session_id", null: false
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "sessions", ["session_id"], name: "index_sessions_on_session_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "sessions", ["updated_at"], name: "index_sessions_on_updated_at", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "login_token"
    t.datetime "login_token_valid_until"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

 add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id", using: :btree

 create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

  create_table "visits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "visited_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Even though i have un-installed the 2 roles-gems, everytime I run rake db:migrate, I get the above schema.

I am using only the "sessions" and "vendors" tables in my app.
Any idea what I should do to get rid of these unwanted tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check if the table is present...**in rails console**...

```
##to view all tables 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

i use `rails console` to delete tables directly...

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("drop table table_name")
    ###========OR===============
    ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
   ###=========OR===============
   ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table("table_name")     
   ###=========WITH EXAMPLE===============
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_table :subscriptions
```

Then,**delete** the migration file or **rename** it again by changing timestamp and again run `rake db:migrate`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, all 3 commands give the error " " : command not found.. Also I have already deleted the migration files related to these tables. But they get generated every time i run rake db:migrate. Any ideas wat I did incorrectly?

Comment: ... dd you run the command in rails console..using rails c...@user6525564

Comment: check if the table is present..i have updated my answer...@user6525564

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't run it in the console. I also assumed that deleting the gems and running rake db:migrate was sufficient to delete the corresponding tables.

Comment: After you do that I would recommend running rake db:schema:dump

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `app/db/migrate` directory. Find and delete the migrations associated with those gems.

Once the migration files are removed, you can run `rake db:migrate` again. Then run `rake db:schema:dump` and check the newly generated `schema.rb` file to make sure you're not retaining any tables for the gems you removed.

Comment: After deleting the migrations associated with those gems you can also simply delete the schema.rb and development.sqlite3 file then run rake db:migrate. This will remove all association with those gems you uninstalled.

Comment: Hi I have only two migration files related to "vendors" and "sessions". I don't have any other migration files at all..And also I use postgres. Maybe I should install a postgres graphic tool and look into that? I have also tried deleting schema.rb and then running db:migrate. The extra tables still persist..

Comment: When you're trying to rerun your migrations, is `rake db:migrate` all you're doing, or are you running other `rake` tasks first?

Comment: I also run rake assets:precompile, before rake db:migrate

Comment: Umm... so you're saying that you *do not* run `rake db:drop` or `rake db:reset`?